# why is my timestamp converted incorrectly

Tags: qt, qdatetime

I'm trying to convert a time stamp in string format to msecs since epoch, like so:

```
QString startTime("20131030 21923"); //2013-10-30 02:19:23 
auto date = QDateTime::fromString(startTime, "yyyyMMdd hmmss");
auto secsSinceEpoch = date.toTime_t();
```

The result (secsSinceEpoch) is 1383163763, which converts to 2013-10-30 21:09:23.
So it seems like my format string is interpreted incorrectly (as "yyyyMMdd hhmss"), why is that so and what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the caveat here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdate.html#fromString-2

> The expressions that don't expect leading zeroes (d, M) **will be
>   greedy**. This means that they will use two digits even if this will put
>   them outside the accepted range of values and leaves too few digits
>   for other sections. For example, the following format string could
>   have meant January 30 but the M will grab two digits, resulting in an
>   invalid date:

so your best be it to split them up and parse separately

edit: for example you can get the date and time with

```
QDate date = QDate::fromString(startTime.left(8), "yyyMMdd");
startTime[8]=0;//replacing the " " with a 0
QTime time = QTime::fromString(startTime.right(6), "hhmmss");//hour becomes a 2 digit
QDateTime fullDate(date,time);
auto secsSinceEpoch = fullDate.toTime_t();
```

Comment: so you're telling me there's no way to have a one digit hour in my string?

Comment: indeed though you can fudge it by manipulating the string a bit (replacing the space with a `0` and taking `startTime.right(6)` for the time while using `startTime.left(8)` for the date

Comment: So... extremely counterintuitive format-strings and a very missleading documentation then. Guess I'll have to use that workaround. Thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of QDateTime, "h" means "the hour without a leading zero" and "hh" means "the hour with a leading zero". So the number of "h" does not necessarily correspond to the number of digits, as in strftime :)

A workaround would be to parse the timestamp into a time_t with std C/C++ functions. Or just add a space between 2 and 1923 and change the expression in fromString accordingly.

Comment: as I understood it "h" means either one digit or two digits. so "02" and "2" should both be okay.

Answer (score 1):

'h' stands for "hour without leading zero". I think there is a logical fallacy in qt documents in http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qdatetime.html

"21923" would stand for 2:19:23 when "mm" is parsed before "h" is. But I guess QT calculates from left to right and 21 is perfectly valid hour value. If it was "31923", your assumptions would be correct, though.

I'd go for a blank char ' ' or semicolon between h and m values if you want to avoid leading zeros.